# One-to-Many PGSQL SELECT into single row with dynamic number of rows mapping to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have data in two tables

```
Order -> Order Items
```

The first table has a Primary Key id

```
id name 
1  order1  
2  order2
3  order3
```

The second table has the order_id from table 1 as foriegn key

```
name   order_id 
item1  1
item2  2
item2  3
```

Query which I am running now is

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.generated_from,
       b.price
FROM   orders AS a
       INNER JOIN order_data AS b
               ON a.id = b.order_id
```

But it is giving me

```
id    name      order_data
 1   order1    item1
 1   order1    item1
 1   order1    item1
 2   order2    item1
 2   order2    item1
 3   order3    item1
 3   order3    item1
 3   order3    item2
 3   order3    item2
```

What I would like the result data to have is:

```
id   order_name         order_data1    order_data2 
 0     order1           item1           item2
 1     order2           item1           item2
 2     order3           null            item2
```

Comment: This sample data does not give such result on this join. In addition, how do you expect order1 to have item2 if sample data nor current result have that kind of relation present? It kinda sounds like you want to do pivot table? [tablefunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html) extension provides such functionality for PostgreSQL

Comment: sample data was manually created based on what I want the result to be..I just had a look at crosstab function that seems to return 3 columns but I want more than 3 columns to be returned as result set